# WPF Button pixelated on one site

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

Every button with the following style is pixelated at the right site. You can see it clearly in the selected (blue) line:

[image]

This is the part of my code which causes the problem:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
      <Border>
        <Border.Background>
          <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
              <Grid Width="80" Height="20">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" RadiusX="13" RadiusY="13">
                  <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                      <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>

                <Rectangle Margin="3,2" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="12">
                  <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                      <GradientStop Color="#dfff" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#0fff" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>

              </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
          </VisualBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <ContentPresenter 
          x:Name="contentPresenter"
          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Does anyone have an idea why the buttons are pixelated on the right site?

Comment: Display driver issue? Update your drivers or try on another machine.

Comment: That would mean it's not pixelated on the screenshot for you. Is this the case?

Comment: I can see the pixelation, but that doesn't rule out a driver issue since you grabbed from your screen. I've had WPF corruption before with bad drivers.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I can't update the drivers at work.

Comment: Have u have ever used another template with image ? I guess somehow, you have different templates and one of them uses image source.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the issue is in your `Button` style.  Here's what your style looks like in my project:

[image]

Your buttons might be inheriting style from other templates? (rectangle, border, etc)

Comment: I commented out every other line which might cause trouble, which were triggers and RenderTransform. It didn't change anything tho. There are no other Styles affecting the buttons.  

I also tried to change the resolution - It had no effect.

Comment: You have no styling with `TargetType Border` or `Rectangle` anywhere in your project?  The style would be inherited.  Might be worth setting the button's style to be `BasedOn` a blank style to just rule it out.

Comment: I have my TargetType Button BasedOn FrameworkElement